# How do I disable auto-indent in Eclipse Helios (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I swear I looked everywhere, and disabled almost everything (insertion of matching brackets etc), but when I type an opening brace and hit enter, it auto-indents the next line with a tab. Is there a way to disable this "handy" "commodity"?

Comment: eh.. why? You want to write unindented code?

Comment: After years of coding in text editors like Gedit/Medit and IDE's simpler than Eclipse, I've developed a habit of indenting manually. I'm still using Medit for PHP/HTML/Javascript so I don't feel like breaking the habit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. From the menu go to **Project > Properties**
2. Select **Java Code Style > Formatter**
3. Check the box for **Enable project specific settings** OR click **Configure Workspace Settings**
4. Click the **Edit...** button for the active profile
5. On the **Indentation** tab uncheck all of the **Indent** options

Comment: Thank you!! I was looking only in Window > Preferences, didn't know they could be somewhere else.

Comment: No problem. It's actually in Window > Preferences as well. Under Java > Code Style > Formatter. As Bozho mentions the search box is excellent for finding these things, it can be hard to find them otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

White Fang gave you the correct answer, but I will give you a guide how to find options that you need:

1. Open Window > Preferences (or Project > Properties)
2. Type the word you need in the search box.

The search in settings is extremely useful. When you type "indent", it would filter the irrelevant items in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do here is to disable smart insert mode completely (Edit > Smart Insert Mode), or configure the Smart Insert Mode (Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing).