# Indentation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, indentation

I am trying to indent my code in eclipse .

```
List<TestDB> list=session.createCriteria(TestDB.class).add(Restrictions.eq("testCase",testCase)).list();
```

I type my code as above and when I save my code the line is indented as follows :-

```
List<TestDB> list = session.createCriteria(TestDB.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("testCase", testCase)).list();
```

I tried this from SO :-
 [How do I disable auto-indent in Eclipse Helios (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769957/how-do-i-disable-auto-indent-in-eclipse-helios-java)
But it is did not help . Can anyone please help me with the indentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Save Actions` -> Deactivate `Perform the selected actions on save.`

Also right click your project, select `Properties` and check the same setting here.