# Is there a way to disable all indentation and other automatic insertion in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, indentation

Is there any way to globally configure all text editors in Eclipse to insert *only* the user's actual keystrokes into the file, and *zero* additional characters?

In particular, is there a way to ensure that typing `ENTER` always inserts exactly `ENTER`, no more, no less, and *never* inserts `ENTER` `SPACE` `SPACE`...`SPACE` for some context-dependent number of spaces?

The behavior will have several desirable (to me) consequences:

- typing `ENTER` `BACKSPACE` would restore the file to its exact state prior to `ENTER`. Currently, roundtripping the state (e.g. to revert an accidental keypress) requires `ENTER` `BACKSPACE` `BACKSPACE` `BACKSPACE` ... `BACKSPACE`.
- typing `ENTER` `ENTER` `ENTER` `ENTER` at any location in the file would produce three completely empty lines and leave the cursor at the extreme left of the fourth line, versus four lines prefixed by `SPACE` `SPACE`...`SPACE` which demand further cleanup.
- Multi-line copy-paste will be 100% predictable and consistent irrespective of context.

This is how *every other basic editor* behaves (or at least can behave), so it seems plausible that this would be achievable in Eclipse, somehow. But although I have found ways to disable every other 'smart' intervention Eclipse throws across my path, I have never found a way to disable the `ENTER` `SPACE` `SPACE`...`SPACE` behavior.

The solution needn't be a built-in configuration parameter (and by this point I doubt such exists). Plugins or other one-time hacks of moderate complexity are acceptable, provided the result is an always-on type-one-key-get-one-character behavior.

*Note, importantly, that invoking an auto-format operation after the fact to clean up unwanted whitespace is a non-solution. I know that works; it's not what I'm looking for.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769957/how-do-i-disable-auto-indent-in-eclipse-helios-java

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite it. `Enter` on a line with N leading spaces still produces a newline with N leading spaces - for all recommended fixes behind the link.