# How can disable indent when I run on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

I want to disable indendation **when I run eclipse**.

I Have made this action but it's not resulting what I want:

1) goto: Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit new profile 
2) On new profile: uncheck all indent box
3) apply

But I still have a indentation when I run eclipse.

Comment: Is your new profile activated? But I'd be curious to know why you don't want indented code!

Comment: yes... why?? by the way, the formatter configuration tells what is done when you call format action, not how is displayed a random file in the editor (the editor always shows blank characters)

Answer (score 0):

To disable auto-indentation:

> [How do I disable auto-indent in Eclipse Helios (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769957/how-do-i-disable-auto-indent-in-eclipse-helios-java)

**Make sure you enable project specific settings OR click Configure Workspace Settings as per your requirement.**

**Note -** If you have Eclipse[built in] as the active profile, then just create a new profile by clicking **New**. Use Eclipse[built in] to initialize settings. Now, edit this new profile to disable the indentation.

To disable auto-formatting:

> https://superuser.com/questions/509148/how-to-disable-template-auto-format-in-eclipse